# How do i hide iAd in IOS 7 when there is no iAd

Tags: ios, iad

I need to know how to hide iAd in IOS 7 when their is no iAd Shown

Here is my code that i am using:

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
     if (!self.bannerIsVisible) 
     {
          [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
          banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
          [UIView commitAnimations];
          self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
     }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 banner.hidden = YES;
```

Also you can try Apple [iAd Guide sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html)